# How to force flush of OutputStream/Writer in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring MVC controller which directly writes to `Writer`.

```
@GetMapping("/delay")
void delay(final java.io.Writer writer) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        writer.write(String.valueOf(i));
        writer.write(",");
        writer.flush();

        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

When I call this method using `curl`, despite calling `flush()` in every loop iteration, it seems `Writer` is only flushed when 1024 bytes are written. Is there a way to force flushing of `Writer` in every loop iteration?

Comment: What is the complete name of the `Writer` class (or interface) ? I cannot seem to find it. Anyways, it maybe wraps a BufferedOutputStream that only flushes every 1024 bytes (but there should be a way to force flush).

Comment: @JeremyGrand Yes, It is `java.io.Writer`.

Comment: It seems flush() is correctly propagated to the underlying `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteWriter` and `org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer`, but the response is not returned until 1k of data has been written to the response

Comment: Have you considered if your issue could be caused by curl ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand Yes, you are right. I tested it with telnet and it works. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems it was `curl` which was doing caching, option `--no-buffer` (`-N`) disables the buffering of the output stream.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the `CoyoteWriter` flushing works fine. I guess a proper unit test would be more convincing that calling a controller with Curl.

I naively tested your code with both curl and a web browser and indeed, curl is outputing the response in bulks whereas the browser is properly reading the response as it is being written.